# What does this slant "equals" sign indicate in this wolfram alpha plot?

Tags: definition, graphing-functions, wolfram-alpha

When plotting the function

$$\frac{(x^2 -1)}{(x^2 -x -2)}$$ with Wolfram alpha, the second plot has a slant "equals" sign right below when the graph hits the y-axis. What does this indicate? And why does the graph not cross the y-axis as in the first plot?

[Plot by wolfram alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%28x%5E2%20-1%29%20%2F%20%28x%5E2%20-x%20-2%29)

[image: Plot by wolfram alpha]

Comment: It indicates a gap in the $y$-axis. If you look at the numerical labels along that axis, you’ll see that the line segment from $0.4$ down to the $x$-axis isn’t nearly as long as it should be: compare it with the gap between $0.4$ and $0.8$, for instance. They simply didn’t include all of the empty space there.

Comment: Makes sense. But why doesn't the graph cross the y-axis?

Comment: I think that the software simply decided to cut it off there. The function has a vertical asymptote at $x=2$, and they just chose a convenient place to stop displyaing it.

Comment: It signifies the axis does not start at zero. In other words the crossing of the axis does not represent the origin

Comment: To be clear, it is only a coincidence that the double slash seems to terminate the curve.